# What is the best vegetation to build a thatch for British climate?

Tags: housing

Thatch as the roof has that advantage, that it is very light and it is done for quickly renewable resources.

But what is the best vegetation to build a thatch for very rainy climate, such as those of British island? From what plants would you build your roof to stay dry even if it's raining for weeks?

Comment: From what I know staying dry isn't the issue - thatch in the UK typically lasts 25 years and only leaks if there's a big hole in it. I expect that the most sustainable material is one you can get locally that would otherwise be burned otherwise discarded. If it's used in some way you're a competing user and the question is the marginal cost of supply and what other use you're displacing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Belgium and the Netherlands there are still quite a few houses with thatched roofs. They are usually houses with higher segments. Making such a roof is quite time consuming (hence the high installation costs, due to labor costs.) The climate is quite similar, if not identical, to the British Islands.

Over here the roofs are made out of [common reed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phragmites)
[image] (Source: WikiCommons)